# UNITY : how to pause baking and quit project?

Tags: unity, lighting

How to pause the lighting bake and quit the project ? so when i re-open the scene it will continue baking without have to start the bake from beginning ?

I need to take a break to do other job on my computer, because after i turn on 'auto generate' , the baking takes very very long. I want to quit unity and continue later.

Right now if i reopen the project , it will bake from start again.

Thanks

Comment: Baking can't be interrupted and restarted.

Comment: that's crazy, i have to wait for ETA 500 hours after leaving it for whole night. :-)  ... for just a low poly house  and simple low poly furnitures.

Comment: I suspect you have other problems

Comment: @andio What hardware are you using? If you are on an ancient or extremely low-end CPU, your computer may just not be suitable for baking lighting. If you have a decent CPU, you may have set up your lighting settings incorrectly.

Comment: @Kevin macbook pro 16, intel i9 - 2.3hz 8 core, radeon 5500M 4GB vram, 16GB RAM. Not a powerful one for 3d, but also not prehistoric laptop :-) . I don't know what is wrong, is this mac version doesn't work well ? or the radeon ? i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Since your hardware should be up to the task of baking, it's time to troubleshoot other possible issues. I can't comment on whether there's an issue with baking in Mac versions of Unity.

Some simple things to try:

1. Upgrade to the latest version of Unity if you haven't already, in case this is a bug they've already fixed.
2. Try creating a new scene in a new project, add a couple of cubes, and bake. If it goes fast, this suggests there's something wrong with the settings or assets in the scene you're trying to bake in your main project.
3. Try switching the lightmapper between "Progressive CPU" and "Progressive GPU" to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks, i 'll try that and see how it goes.